# Deleting uneccessary kernels

Tags: package-management

I installed synaptic package manager to manage my packages and, I see many kernels, that are not being used, can I delete them? There are 2 - 3 using kernels and many non using.

Comment: What do you mean by "cores" ? CPU cores, or something else ? Please [edit] your question and clarify what exactly you mean, and what the problem is.

Comment: linux-generic, linux-generic-extra

Comment: Kernels, you mean - I'd recommend leaving them, and they only take up a few MBs of space anyway, and don't use any other resources. Removing the wrong one may render your computer unbootable !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purge old kernels: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/06/purge-old-kernels.html

If you're using Xenial, it's included in the Byobu package, so you can run it straightaway if you have that installed:
`sudo purge-old-kernels`

If you're using an earlier version of Ubuntu, then you can download the script from here: https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kirkland/byobu/trunk/download/head:/purgeoldkernels-20160229030309-vgiaonyu553ugyrz-1/purge-old-kernels

Just make it executable and run it:

```
chmod +x purge-old-kernels
sudo ./purge-old-kernels
```

Comment: In Xenial the script is installed via the `byobu` package, which is only installed by default on the server.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Edited accordingly, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete packages at random!! You will end up breaking system functionality. To delete unnecessary packages, open a Terminal window and type:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will delete very old kernels too. Ubuntu (and other linuxes) are keeping 2 or more kernel versions installed at all times as backup. If one kernel fails for any number of reasons, the next one will automatically boot instead. This ensures a 100% fail-proof operation. Not like stupid Windows with just one kernel and multiple blue screens.